# Convert string to list if string is json like but contains '?

Tags: python, json, string, list, type-conversion

I want to make this a list object but the ' in *Sample's Rd* made it pretty hard.

I tried:

json.load(), split() and strip() and ast.literal_eval()

`[{'long_name': 'Sample's Road', 'short_name': 'Sample's Rd', 'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': 'England', 'short_name': 'England', 'types': ['boo', 'far']}]`

I need a solution that I can also use for other instances without a ' in the name and that have a different number of key-value pairs.

Comment: *How* did you try those things?

Comment: If you are trying to make a list of the values you could simply iterate over the values of each dictionary, something like:
```output = [f.values() for f in yourListHere]```

Comment: Use `json.dumps(my_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

I could give you a solution:
the problem is " ' " in the key that is parsed in the dictionary. We have to get rid of that, so we make a list as a string, remove the " ' " and then make a JSON of that.

```
import ast
import re
#list_string = "<your_list>"
list_string = "[{'long_name': 'Sample's Road', 'short_name': 'Sample's Rd', 
     'types': 
     ['route']}, {'long_name': 'England', 'short_name': 'England', 'types': 
     ['boo', 'far']}]"
# remove the extra "`" between words for specific word
# - > list_string = list_string.replace("e's", "e s")
#remove the extra "`" between words for all words
new_string = re.sub('{[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]}:', '', list_string)
# now your problem has been solved, turn the string to list and dump it

final_list = ast.literal_eval(new_string)
json.dumps(final_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was a bit unclear in my question. Sorry. The solution need to work for unknown instances of these strings. There could also be a St'Georges Road or sth. similar that I don't know. You replacing step would therefore just work for this one instance...

Comment: I rewrite the substitution line to one more general.

Comment: What I did now is converting all the other "'" to '"' - seems to be more general and it seems to work for my test cases.   `x = (
            x.replace("{'", '{"')
            .replace("': '", '": "')
            .replace("', '", '", "')
            .replace("': ['", '": ["')
            .replace("']}", '"]}')
        )`

Comment: I think if the values stay in the string, this solution may work, but consider its values to be listed or dictionary inside the dictionary. there ganna be mess.